# Disable Checkbox with NSDialogs

Tags: installation, nsis

Does NSDialogs have a function that allows you to disable a CheckBox widget? If not I guess the only method is native WinAPI functions.

I've looked through NSDialogs api but cant find any disable functions

**Edit:** It appears I am having difficulty doing this even with WinAPI functions(SendMessage) any ideas why?

```
${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 12u 67u 45u 10u "Version 10"
Pop $myChkBx
SendMessage $myChkBx ${WM_ENABLE} "FALSE" "FALSE"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres how to do it:

```
EnableWindow $myChkBx 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrong point of your attempt is that you were passing two strings `FALSE` to the `SendMessage` instead of the false value that is `0`.

```
SendMessage $myChkBx ${WM_ENABLE} 0 0
```

Comment: @kdmin are you sure that the `$myChkBx` was correct? Do you have any warning in the NSIS compilation log?

Comment: yes, I am sure: the proof of that is that code provided by Jake worked just fine, so it should not be a problem with $myChkBx... No compilation warnings also.